# Using DotnetZip with Visual Studio C++/CLR

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, dotnetzip

I tried to use DotNetZip with C++/CLR But I found everyfile i downloaded contain no .h file, in the example code, there is **"using namespace Ionic::Zip;"**
How can I get that to work in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the DotnetZip DLL.  Once the reference to the DLL is added the compiler will process the metadata in the DLL and make the types and methods available to you in the same way it does by processing a header file.  To add a reference do the following

- Right click on the project in "Solution Explorer" and select "References"
- Click the "Add New Reference" button
- Select the "Browse" tab and navigate to the DotnetZip DLL

Comment: Thanks, I am really new to CLR

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that don't need to use `Visual Studio GUI` is to add directly a `#using` directive in each `CPP` source file that uses `Ionix.zip`.

Example:

```
#using <Ionic.Zip.dll>

using namespace Ionic::Zip;
```

If `using namespace` is not used, `#using` is interesting to document which sources are using `Ionix.Zip`. If `using namespace` is used, it is more interesting to put this directive in Project's reference as proposed by JaredPar.